# Grouping rows when values are equals or null in sql server

Tags: sql-server

In Sql Server, I'm trying to group matching rows by ids.

Null is considered a wildcard.

**Explanation: What does matching rows mean?**

Matching rows means – just if all columns of two rows match.

Match column mean – same value ('A' = 'A') or null value for each value ('A'/'B'/'C'/... = NULL).

**In my example:**

Row 1 matches Row 2 – 
Because:

First column: 'A' = 'A'

Second column: 'B' = NULL

Third column: NULL = 'C'

Row 1 **does not** match Row 4 :

First column: 'A' = 'A'

**Second column: 'B' != 'D'**

Third column: NULL = NULL.

The comparison failed because the values in second column that do not match.

Can anyone help me with the sql?

**For example:**

For creating the test table:

```
create table test_table (
    id int,
    column1 varchar(20),
    column2 varchar(20),
    column3 varchar(20)
);

insert into test_table (id, column1, column2, column3) values 
(1, 'A', 'B', NULL),
(2, 'A',NULL, 'C'),
(3, 'A', 'B', 'D'),
(4, NULL, 'D', NULL),
(5, 'A', 'B', 'D');
```

The table for example

[image: the table]

This is the expected result:

```
group id 1: {1,2}
group id 2: {1,3,5}
group id 3: {2,4}
```

and **not** the group: {1,2,3}.

example of the expected result in a table:

[expected result in a table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQ2l0.png)

Comment: Not clear what is the requirement logic?

Comment: Row 5 matches every other row. 1 and 2 match. Etc. So as Suraj has indicated, your logic is not clear.

Comment: Sorry. I fixed the example. Is it clear now?

Answer (score 1):

You need to skip a particular column join condition whenever either value is `NULL`, so just use a few `OR` with `IS NULL`. Try this:

```
SELECT
    T1.id,
    T2.id
FROM
    test_table AS T1
    INNER JOIN test_table AS T2 ON
        (T1.column1 = T2.column1 OR T1.column1 IS NULL OR T2.column1 IS NULL) AND
        (T1.column2 = T2.column2 OR T1.column2 IS NULL OR T2.column2 IS NULL) AND
        (T1.column3 = T2.column3 OR T1.column3 IS NULL OR T2.column3 IS NULL)
WHERE
    T1.id < T2.id -- Only display relationships in one way (<)
```

This isn't a group operation (as your title suggests), it's a join between records.

Comment: Thank you. This is a good solution if I want to get pairs of ids. but I want to get groups that can contain more than two items. I updated the example above to make it clearer.